# css star rating with radio buttons in mvc5 razor view

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a view to create a record in my table. One of fielding is a rating which consists of radio buttons 1-7.

I want to convert my form-group in my view to have a css star rating like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Musango/dfoj5s1g/#&togetherjs=yyTtSDpouo) based on that code.

This is the code for my form group in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "1")
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "2")
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "3")
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "4")
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "5")
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "6")
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "7")


                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
```

I need to convert the code in html component jsfiddle in mvc5 html helper code which I'm not sure how to do

Comment: So what is the problem ? Are you getting an error ?

Comment: I need to convert the code in html component jsfiddle in mvc5 html helper code which I'm not sure how to do

Comment: So your current code(with the needed css) will generate the Stars for the radio buttons. What is not working ?

Comment: it not a question of what not working. I want to find out how to right this 

<input type="radio" id="rating-5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="rating-5">5</label>

 into this format:

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "1")

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "1", new { id = "rating-1" }) <label for="rating-1">1</label>`

Comment: `<span class="star-cb-group">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Rating, "1", new { id = "rating-1" }) <label for="rating-1">1</label></span>` 

is there a way to span class into that format of code.  Right now if I add the span class just like about, When I select a star it only records one as the value